# CSS3 z-index issue with transform:rotate()

Tags: html, css

In the following example, why do the last items in the 5 and 6-element lists overlap with item #2? How is item #1 on top of the last item? Is it possible to fix this so the last item will be under items #1 AND #2?

http://jsfiddle.net/lookitscook/adw62/

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty ridiculous technique! And by ridiculous, I mean COOL :)

Z-index is initially defined by DOM position - the latest items in the DOM will appear on top of the others.

You can manually control this by setting "z-index" properties on each of the elements.

Comment: Thanks Josh! I'm not sure it's quite that simple in this case. If that was 100% true here item #1 would be below the last item. Why item #1 is always on top is the real question.